# Close VB.net application and make icon disappear

Tags: vb.net

Executing the exe file,

it will open the program and create a icon on the right-bottom windows status bar.

After processing some functions,

it will call Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode) and Application.Exit()

and close the application.

But the icon on the windows status bar still exist,

how to make the icon disappear?

[image]

Comment: Have you set the `Visible = False`? Sample: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/75822/create-a-system-tray-application-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you kill your application you can set your icon to nothing. So that your application Icon will remove from system tray.

```
YourForm.Icon = Nothing
```